# What would be the best practice of Scala to have a method accept two different models

Tags: scala, json4s

Currently I have a method that accept `ModelA` and know to perform actions on it.

so in my controller I accept request of `ModelA` and call this method with it.

And now, I want to be able to accept request of `ModelB`, map the request to be of `ModelA` (cause it has the same data just not all of it and in different names), and call this method with it.

lets say the method would look like:

```
def myMethod(data: ModelA): ResModel = {
    // do something with data
}
```

my controller currrently would be:

```
def doActions(): Action[JValue] = { request => 
    val dataExctracted = request.body.extract[ModelA]
    myMethod(dataExctracted)
    ...
}
```

and both of my models are just case classes in seperate files:

```
case class ModelA(a: String, b: String, c: String)

case class ModelB(aAsDifferentName: String, bAsDifferntName: String)
```

What would be the best practice of Scala to have the myMethod accept both Models (without `Either`) ? and how the controller should look like in reaction to that?

is there also a classic way to return different models without having to accept the calls in different controller methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Have them Implement a dummy trait and do pattern matching on type.

Comment: How are you going to decide what type to extract from the `request.body`?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to model the union type (like `Int | String` in Dotty).

Something like this:

```
scala> case class Or[A, B](a: A, b: B)
defined class Or

scala> def test(v: Int Or String): String = {
     | v.toString
     | }
test: (v: Or[Int,String])String

scala> implicit def Int2Or(x: Int): Int Or String = Or(x, "")
Int2Or: (x: Int)Or[Int,String]

scala> implicit def String2Or(x: String): Int Or String = Or(-1, x)
String2Or: (x: String)Or[Int,String]

scala> test(1)
res0: String = Or(1,)

scala> test("")
res1: String = Or(-1,)
```

The cool thing is, you can use the `Or` class like this `String Or Boolean`, but this is definitely not the *real* union type from Dotty.

In my opinion the strait forward solution is using a sealed trait and do pattern matching.

Comment: The issue is how do you know what `Or(-1, "")` is? case class is a product type when what we want is a union type (sealed trait). The straight-forward solution is to do neither and use a different route! :p

Comment: @AndyHayden good point! Sure, as I said, more simple solution is to use trait or even overloaded methods.

Comment: How is this an improvement on just using `Either`? OP said they didn't want to use `Either`, but your `Or` is just `Either` under a different name, except (as Andy points out) mis-implemented.